# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack while creating a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

As shown below, I am trying to create a new dictionary(student) using existing lists : keys and values;

Values list has one of its elements already a list defined outside as courses.

```
student = {}
keys = ['name', 'age', 'courses']

courses = ['Python', 'Linux', 'Selenium Webdriver']

values = ['Kapil', '29', courses]

student = {key:value for key, value in zip(keys + values)}

print (student)
```

When i run this i get the following error:

[Error while creating dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nonXF.png)

Comment: `zip(keys + values)` => `zip(keys,values)`

Answer (score 0):

when doing

```
for key, value in zip(keys + values)
```

`zip` yields a `tuple` made with 1 element, iterating through the list of `keys` joined with `values` (`zip` can take from 1 to any number of arguments), and 1 value doesn't fit in 2 target values. So you're not really zipping the keys with the values but you're *adding* them...

You need:

```
for key, value in zip(keys,values)
```

in your case, you'd be better off with passing the tuples directly to `dict` instead of dict comprehension:

```
student = dict(zip(keys,values))
```